# Como fazer a compactação de Imagens em Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, imagem, xamarin-forms, bitmap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `Xamarin.Forms` que utiliza a câmera do celular para capturar imagens, porém, dependendo do celular do cliente a imagem pode chegar até a 12MB, isso é demais para nosso servidor.

Durante minhas buscas, descobri que a classe `Bitmap` do `System.Drawing` funciona somente com Windows e não com o Xamarin, então eliminei essa possibilidade.

Em alguns lugares descobri que poderia usar o `Bitmap` do Xamarin, então fiz o seguinte:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    ImageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    Bitmap imagemBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(ImageBytes, 0, ImageBytes.Length);
    imagemBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 5, ms);

    bytesCompactados = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Porém, infelizmente, independente da qualidade que eu coloco entre os parenteses do `Compress`, seja 0 ou 100, ele não interfere em nada e acaba aumentando o tamanho da imagem ao envés de diminuir.

Para diminuir o tamanho, pode ser alterando a resolução e/ou fazendo a compactação da qualidade da imagem.

Alguém sabe como corrigir isso, ou talvez tenha uma ideia de um jeito melhor de fazer isso? Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você usa o CrossMedia para tirar as fotos você pode configurar a compressão da imagem direto dele, segue um exemplo de código:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
            {

                CompressionQuality = 40 // vai de 0 a 100, quanto menor for menor a qualidade, consequentemente menor o tamanho também.

            });
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu mesmo!!

Comment: @RenanMussatto Boa mano, não esquece de marcar como resposta aceita